# Should I use 'follow lemma (1)' or 'follow from lemma (1)'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, phrases, mathematics

In mathematical papers,  some theorems are proved based on some existing lemmas.

Then, should I use

> Following lemma (1), we prove...

or

> Following from lemma (1), we prove...

Comment: Something follows from a lemma, but I think you'll have to rewrite from scratch, because the real culprit is the "we prove". For two reasons. First off, you only write "we prove" in an abstract, but never in the proof proper. There, you just go ahead and prove. Second off, "following from lemma 1, we prove X" is sort of nonsensical. Either it follows, or you prove. You can't have both. If you have to prove, then it doesn't follow. If it follows, then there's nothing left to prove. So the typical wording is "it directly follows from lemma 1 that X", or "X follows directly from lemma 1".

Answer (score 2):

**Follow from** is the standard way to use follow in this sense.

From [oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/follow?q=follows): (sense 2.2)

> [NO OBJECT] Be a logical consequence of something
>
> *it thus **follows from** this equation that the value must be negative*

If you want to say that X results from lemma (1), you could say:

> X follows from lemma(1)

or

> From lemma(1), X follows.

You shouldn't use `we prove`, as RegDwight pointed out in their comment.

If X is very long and you must include it last, go for:

> Following from lemma (1), we have... X

Answer (score 1):

Just say:

> By/From lemma X, ...

Or if it is a complicated one and you want to make clear what you are using the lemma on:

> By applying lemma X to object Y, we get/obtain ...